# Managed pointers in .NET 6+

Tags: pointers, .net-core, c++-cli, dotnetcorecli

I'm trying to port an existing c++ library to .net 6. I have set the framework version and CLR support flag:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
...
<CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
```

I get the compilation error

```
CurrentProject.cpp(9,88): error C3699: '^': cannot use this indirection on type 'System::ComponentModel::PropertyChangedEventHandler'
CurrentProject.cpp(9,88): message : compiler replacing '^' with '*' to continue parsing
CurrentProject.cpp(9,88): message : This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'ArcGIS::Desktop::Framework::Contracts::PropertyChangedBase' from assembly 'ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework, Version=13.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86'.
CurrentProject.cpp(9,88): message : This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'ArcGIS::Desktop::Core::Project' from assembly 'ArcGIS.Desktop.Core, Version=13.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86'.
CurrentProject.cpp(9,88): fatal  error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

And the line in question is

```
ArcGIS::Desktop::Core::Project ^curProject = ArcGIS::Desktop::Core::Project::Current;
```

Does netcore not support managed pointers?

Comment: That is definitely not the line in question, the error is with an event assignment.

Comment: I'm not saying that's where the problem is, I'm saying that's where the compiler is pointing to. There is no event assignment in the project.

Comment: @Blindy: That line definitely does cause the compiler to import type `ArcGIS::Desktop::Core::Project`... the compiler diagnostics say the error occurred while importing the type.

Comment: @BenVoigt I know, but he edited that after I commented.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of the explanation but I found that removing the `System` reference from the vcxproj file solved this.

```
<Reference Include="System" />
```

This doesnt seem to be needed in NetCore but was probably needed in the old NetFramework CLR.